# PHP How right parse xml?

Tags: php, xml

[category.php](http://testwork.ru/test/2/category.txt)

```
<?php
include 'category.php';

$lines = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

var_dump($lines);
?>
```

[result script we can see here](http://testwork.ru/test/2/test.php)

When we make this script we get error `Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 3: parser error : xmlParseEntityRef: no name in /var/www/seo-main/data/www/testwork.ru/test/2/test.php on line 4`

Tell me please why i get this error and how right output on display array elements ?

Comment: That is not a well-formed XML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the special character & in node's attribute. You need to replace them all.

```
<Category ID="38399" ParentID="1" Name="Antiquitäten & Kunst" Type="Normal" Channels="AuctionFixed" HasChildren="true" SortMask="0100653839900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" Level="1"/>
```

replace with

```
<Category ID="38399" ParentID="1" Name="Antiquitäten &amp; Kunst" Type="Normal" Channels="AuctionFixed" HasChildren="true" SortMask="0100653839900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" Level="1"/>
```